# git merge master into several branches in one step

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Scenario:

I have master and several braches

- customer_1
- customer_2
- customer_3

Master is the project with default configuration.

Each branch "customer_" is the project for "customer_" with his own configuration.

Now I update master with a new feature and I want merge master into customer branches, but I don't want modify config files in branches with default values.

Is it possible in one step, or I have to do this manually after a fetch in each branch?

P.S. I can't put branch config file into gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

If changing your repository structure isn't an option, then cherry-picking is what you want to do. It can be used to copy code from one branch to another - and has to be done for every branch.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

If you're only dealing with changing customer configurations per repository, FIRST, please realize you're running a security risk if you are committing passwords - like database login data - to git.

If you don't care about that, I'd suggest breaking configuration data into a separate repository.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

If you *do* care about that, but find you still need to store the passwords somehow, you should be able to encrypt the submodule's repository. with somthing like git-crypt.